# Changing page using pagecontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uipagecontrol

I need some help to implement the function that change the page on pagecontroller. I have a `UIPageController` , the number of pages is variable.

Here is my code :

.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *vosvehiculeScrollView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageControlVehiculePossedee;
- (IBAction) changePage:(id) sender;
- (void) loadScrollViewWithPage: (int) page;
```

***.m****

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self getVehicules]; 

    vosvehiculeScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

    vosvehiculeScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    vosvehiculeScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    vosvehiculeScrollView.scrollsToTop = NO;

    pageControlVehiculePossedee.numberOfPages=[vehiculesPossede count];

    pageControlVehiculePossedee.currentPage=0;

    [self loadScrollViewWithPage:0];

    votreVehiculeLabel.text=@"Votre véhicule";
    vehiculesPossedesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Annee modele", @"Transmission",@"Carburant", nil];

}

- (void) loadScrollViewWithPage: (int) page {
    if (page < 0) return;
    if (page >= [vehiculesPossede count]) return;    

    tableViewVehiculesPossedes=[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3, 80, 315, 171) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    tableViewVehiculesPossedes.bounces=NO;
    tableViewVehiculesPossedes.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [tableViewVehiculesPossedes setDelegate:self];
    [tableViewVehiculesPossedes setDataSource:self];        
    [self.vosvehiculeScrollView addSubview:tableViewVehiculesPossedes];

    nameVehiculeLabel.text=[[vehiculesPossede objectAtIndex:page] valueForKey:@"modele"];

    self.transmissionString=[[vehiculesPossede objectAtIndex:page]valueForKey:@"transmision"];
    self.carburantString=[[vehiculesPossede objectAtIndex:page] valueForKey:@"carburant"];    
    self.anneeModelString=[[vehiculesPossede objectAtIndex:page] valueForKey:@"modele_annee"];
    self.anneeString=[[vehiculesPossede objectAtIndex:page]valueForKey:@"annee"];

    if(page==0){
        NSLog(@"0");  
    }
    else NSLog(@"1");

}


- (IBAction) changePage:(id) sender
{
    NSLog(@"page changed");
   /* CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.vosvehiculeScrollView.frame.size.width * self.pageControlVehiculePossedee.currentPage;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = self.vosvehiculeScrollView.frame.size;
    NSLog(@"current page %d",pageControlVehiculePossedee.currentPage);
    [self.vosvehiculeScrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];*/

    [self loadScrollViewWithPage:1];
    pageControlUsed = YES;    
}
```

and I get `Program received signal: “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”`. How should I implement the changePage method to make it ok? Please help..

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Where do you receive `Program received signal: “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”`? When?

Comment: I get at line     [self loadScrollViewWithPage:1]; from method changePage when I select the pagecontroller to go to next page

Comment: Is `vehiculesPossede ` valid? Where do you set it?

Comment: yes,it is valid. vehiculesPossede is a NSArray that I receive from a php script

Comment: So if you call `[vehiculesPossede count]` before `[self loadScrollViewWithPage:1];` and after `NSLog(@"page changed");` app is  not crashed on line `[vehiculesPossede count]`?

Comment: no because I call     [self getVehicules]; first at all, and at this line I get the vehiculesPossed array

Comment: i think you want to add tables in scrollview so you need to add tag to each table for to identify the tables . you are allocation same table without release from method change page

Comment: now I have this method : -(void)pageAction:(UIPageControl*)control
{       
    NSLog(@"page changed"); 
    [self getVehicules];
    [tableViewVehiculesPossedes release];
    int page = pageControlVehiculePossedee.currentPage;
    NSLog(@"page %d", page);
    [self loadScrollViewWithPage:page];

    CGRect frame = pageControlVehiculePossedee.frame;
    frame.origin.x = (vosvehiculeScrollView.frame.size.width * page);
    [vosvehiculeScrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
}

Comment: and I see the text from labels (from cell's of tabelview) overlay ...where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I did as follow

```
- (IBAction)actionBtnNext:(id)sender
   {    
       if (pageNumber == kNumberOfPages-2) {
            pageNumber = kNumberOfPages-2;
       }
       else {
            pageNumber++;
       }

       CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width*pageNumber;
       [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(pageWidth,0.0) animated:YES];
 }
```

Let me know if you do have any questions.

Regards